# Difference between fmod and %

Tags: php

I read a lot of text about the "issue" but I am not sure that I found concrete answer. I used "%" for this operation, but recently I stuck at following snippet before using *fmod*. 
Now code works fine but I still do not know difference between % and fmod. I would be thankful if I get answer at least for the snippet.

```
$p = 19;
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
    $c = pow($i, 3) + pow($i, 2)*$p;
    $c = pow($c, 1/3);
    var_dump([fmod($c, 1), $c%1]);
}
```

Comment: probably instead of `1/3` you need `1.0/3.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that `fmod` returns the floating point remainder of the division whereas `%` will always return an integer. Note that modulus `%` strips the fractional part of any input before processing.